# Express subroute router, without having to use full path in each route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm splitting out part of the overall API as a separate subroute, i.e. (code simplified for this question)

```
const mainRouter = express.Router();
const bananaRouter = express.Router();
const appleRouter = express.Router();

bananaRouter.get('/banana/hello', (req, res) => { /* ... */ });

mainRouter.all('/banana/*', bananaRouter);
mainRouter.all('/apple/*', appleRouter);
```

This works. But I don't want to specify the full '/banana/hello' in every single route, and would much prefer '/hello'.

How can I do that?

Comment: What about using `mainRouter.use('banana', bananaRouter)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.use()` with a path prefix (no wildcard) instead of `.all()`.  `.use()` will automatically match a path prefix without a wildcard whereas `.get()` and `.all()` will not and this will then set up your router better.  So, do this to register the router:

```
// send all /banana prefixed urls to the bananaRouter
mainRouter.use('/banana', bananaRouter);
```

Then, inside of that router, you don't use the `/banana` part of the path:

```
// will match /banana/hello
bananaRouter.get('/hello', (req, res) => { /* ... */ });
```

In general, you will use `.use()` for routers and other middleware, not `.all()`.

Comment: Had no idea .use() can be used for routers, not just middlewares, or maybe routers are middlewares?

Comment: @Max - Without regard for what is/isn't middleware, `.use()` has a specific set of features that are useful in many different ways.  It's more important to just understand how `.use()` is different than `.all()` and then you can use whichever is more appropriate for your specific situation.